# Location change even when phone is kept on the table

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

When getting location from the android location manager, I face an issue. Even when I am sitting at a place and not moving, the latitude and longitude I get in onLocationChange() listener are always changing. I have set the update time 500ms and update distance as 5 meters. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: You can ignore small changes of lat lng

Comment: I want exact location of mine.I can not ignore changes to the lat long.

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: @frozenOne You need to check the distance between the 2 points and phone sensors to know if the device really moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPS offset is arround 8 meters for normal phones and about 15-20 meters for old ones. You can set the minimum distance for more than 15 meters and it should help.
In case you are using NETWORK provider, than it takes it's locations from WiFi routers and Cellolar towers. in that case, if the phone changes a cell tower or pick up a new WiFi, than the location might change by more than then 20 meters (20-70 meters for WiFi and 500-1500 meters for cell towers).

Another thing you can do is to take into account the accuracy parameter of the locations you are getting, it should give you a rough estimate on the provider error (E.G. GPS vs Network vs WiFi) and you can try to understand if the phone is moving or not by calculating:

```
if (position_A.distanceTo(position_B) - position_B.getAcuracy() >0){
    do something. //location change.
}
```

**Update**
see that for clarification, while the blue dot is the location your device gives you, the actual location can be anywhere in the blue radius.
[image]

Comment: what about a an app which is dependent on the number of steps or the distance walked by the person like google fit?

Comment: What about it? I'm talking about the GPS sensor, not the program which uses it.

Comment: yea...how to manage the distance. It must be accurate to 1 meters but even when i do not move the distance changes.